# CSV Large File Split for Import into phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

**Currently I am trying to import 1.3 GB CSV into MySQL via phpMyAdmin.**

**Problem:**
Having difficultly splitting the file and then importing it,after splitting using a windows program some of the columns become corrupted.

**Question:**
Is it possible to upload the entire thing into phpMyAdmin without having to split it?

**Information**
I have 5 columns in phpMyAdmin, and so does the CSV so columns match up.

Comment: My suggestion is to write a script that iterate over csv file. Get row data and insert into database.

Comment: I solve a problem like this by writing a python script but your data is too large

Answer (score 0):

Probably this type of issue is face by other [user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717277/how-can-i-import-a-large-14-gb-mysql-dump-file-into-a-new-mysql-database) also.

According to his answer, you can use.

```
mysql -u root -p

set global net_buffer_length=1000000; --Set network buffer length to a large byte number

set global max_allowed_packet=1000000000; --Set maximum allowed packet size to a large byte number

SET foreign_key_checks = 0; --Disable foreign key checking to avoid delays,errors and unwanted behaviour

source file.sql --Import your sql dump file

SET foreign_key_checks = 1; --Remember to enable foreign key checks when procedure is complete!
```

Also check out another method

```
mysql -u username -p -h hostname databasename < dump.sql
```