# Trying to import database: MySQL server has gone away

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Running this command:

```
mysql -u root -p dev_db < dev.sql
```

Error:

```
ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 454: MySQL server has gone away
```

I already added this line to `/etc/my.cnf` (which most other answers on StackOverflow suggest):

```
max_allowed_packet=32M
wait_timeout = 600
```

Comment: The duplicate question this is linked to is not the correct solution. The answer was actually here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717277/how-can-i-import-a-large-14-gb-mysql-dump-file-into-a-new-mysql-database

Comment: How long does it run before timing out?

Comment: @RickJames maybe 45 seconds

Comment: `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` defaults to 50 sec; I wonder if it could be relevant.